# 120v DC Agitator motor, 240v 5500w heating element

Tags: dc-motor

Full disclosure: Not an electrician, mostly clueless.

Setting: Home Brewing Beer

Short: 
120v DC variable drive motor running full tilt when 240v AC 5500w element is connected to mash tun.

Long:
I have a 50 gallon brew kettle with a 240v 5500w AC heating element. The element has variable power supply. Recently I added a 120v DC variable speed motor to agitate the mash (stirring 50 gallons of mash by hand gets really old). The motor work appropriately when the heating element is not attached to a power supply; I can adjust the speed of the motor.

When the heating element is attached to its power supply, the agitator motor runs at full speed, and cannot be adjusted. I spoke with the manufacturer and they suggested that I have an electrician come out.

My house was built in the 20's and has lots of "character". Many of the circuits are not grounded. That being said, I am (fairly) certain the circuit that the agitator is running on is grounded, as well as the heating element.

Thoughts?
Places to start trouble-shooting?

Comment: "The motor work appropriately when the heating element is not attached to a power supply" Huh... You may want to draw a sketch how you wired all that up.

Comment: Home Improvement SE https://diy.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for that question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear how you've wired it up. Does the DC motor have its own speed controller (motor drive)? Or are you connecting the DC motor to the same adjustable power supply as the heating element?

It's probably fair to say that connecting both the heating element and motor to the same adjustable power supply is a bad idea - unless it's specifically designed to drive motors.

Is the DC motor's adjustable speed drive actually designed for running DC motors? If you use a simple "lamp dimmer" style power supply (like you'd use for a heating element) on a motor, you will get undesirable effects such as the motor stuck on full speed - or even damaging consequences. This happens due to the inductance of the motor. A proper motor drive is designed to cope with this.

If you're using a correct motor drive for the motor and a separate power supply for the heater, then this problem shouldn't occur. The fact it does tells me something is very wrong with the AC wiring. Perhaps there is a poor connection in the building's wiring allowing spikes to occur when the heater PWM switches on and off. This could upset the motor drive causing it to run full speed. Try using a long extension cord to connect the motor to a different outlet in the building. Does the problem persist? I would definitely recommend involving an electrician in this situation since poor connections could pose a fire risk.

As far as grounding goes, you really need to be sure that you're properly grounded. If necessary, run a separate ground wire for the installation to a place you know a decent ground is available. I don't think it will affect the performance of the motor much, but it could mean the matter between life and death. Most heating elements for liquids rely on a ground connection for essential safety. If you really can't get a ground connection, you need to run the heater from an isolation transformer. Unfortunately at 5500 watts, it will be a very large and expensive transformer. But how much value do you put on your life?

Comment: Thanks Foxie!
I am using the motor drive provided by the manufacturer. 
The supply circuits are distinct: a 120v 8A breaker supplies the motor and drive and is grounded, a 240v 30A breaker supplies the heating element and SSR control box.  

Sounds like it is time to shut the whole system down and call in a pro. 

Thanks again!